# How to stop duplicate entries into database

Tags: php, mysql, loops, insert, duplicates

Hi there i am trying to insert an array of information into fields in a database through the selection of checkboxes i have that sorted and inserting fine but i am able to insert duplicates which is no good  i am using the following to insert the items

```
    $list = $_POST['sub'];

    // for each loop to insert each value into the database with the selected users informtion
    foreach ($list as  $value)  {

        // The query to run
        $listQuery='INSERT INTO tbl_list (`userId`, `subId`) VALUES (\'' . $id . '\', \'' . $value . '\')';


        // Run the query
        $objects->query($listQuery);


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a unique key for (`userId`, `subId`):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_list ADD UNIQUE(`userId`, `subId`)
```

Then, you should use either `INSERT IGNORE` or `REPLACE INTO` to avoid errors during insert.

Comment: Thank you this was the solution this has had me stuck for a while really appreciate the help

Comment: @ChrisBench in [other comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541235/how-to-stop-duplicate-entries-into-database/15541377#comment22019651_15541255) you've indicated there are 3 fields in your table.  If you use this code as is - you've probably substituted your original question for a different problem. This answer answers exactly the question (+1 incidentally) - but it looks like "the question" isn't your real problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [Insert Ignore](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-handling-duplicates.htm) instead of `Insert` in mysql query

Answer (score 0):

For stop duplicate entries into database you have do this thing.follow step by step

```
> 1.set a unique key on the table

after Complete create unique key you have to decide what you want to do when there's a duplicate

> 2. ignore it

> 3.Overwrite the previously entered record

> Update some counter
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to do two things
first make your userId primary key and then try this query
$listQuery='INSERT INTO tbl_list (`userId`, `subId`) VALUES (\'' . $id . '\', \'' . $value . '\') on duplicate key update userId = LAST_INSERT_ID()';

Comment: It's a join table - making userId the primary key means a user can only have one record for all 'lists'

Comment: But chirs also want the same. He doesn't want duplicate record.

Comment: It' one possibility - but I doubt it. See comments by OP to other answers.

Comment: Hi there am recieving this  error when altering the table #1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: If there are already some duplicate entries in the table then it will make the same error while creating primary key so you need to remove duplicates first.